# Microsoft Dynamics Integration tracking on Campaign level

Tags: marketing-cloud, integration

With the Microsoft Dynamics Integration can reporting be rolled up into Campaign level tracking.

For the [Microsoft Dynamics 2011/2013 Integration](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/) there is reference to [sending emails tied to Campaigns](https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/sending/), but when that data is returned to Dynamics I would like the Dynamics reporting to roll up tracking at the Campaign level not just the Email level.

Comment: Hi @victorcorey, can you provide some more context to your question to help potential answerers. Maybe a link to the MS Dynamics integration product in question. Do you want to take information stored in ExactTarget and sync it into MS Dynamics campaigns?

Comment: For the Microsoft Dynamics 2011/2013 Integration (https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/) there is reference to sending emails tied to Campaigns (https://help.exacttarget.com/sv/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/exacttarget_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/sending/), but when that data is returned to Dynamics I would like the Dynamics reporting to roll up tracking at the Campaign level not just the Email level.